# Margin top and box shadow not working in tbody

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Provided my CSS and HTML code in the code snippet below. I tried to apply box-shadow to every `row` of my `tbody`, but it doesn't work.

Neither does `box-shadow` work, even `margin-top` isn't working.

I wanted to create some spaces between the `thead` and `tbody`. Did I miss out something?

```css
#myList {
  background: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 6%;
}
#myList thead {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 50%;
}
#myList tbody {
  margin-top: 20%;
}
#myList tbody td:first-child {
  display: none;
}
#myList tbody tr {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
#myList tbody td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50%;
}
#myList tbody td {
  color: #00496B;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<table id="myList">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Product Name</td>
      <td>Qty</td>
      <td>Price</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>P1</td>
      <td>Adidas Superstar</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>$50</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> Update

Is it possible if I want to achieve something like what is in the below table? Each item, for instance `Item 1` and `Item 2` is each a row of the tbody.

```
 -------------------
|     Item 1        |
 ------------------

 -------------------
|     Item 2        |
 ------------------
```

Comment: Using pseudo class in css can achieve this. See the sample snippet added below

Comment: can u check the updated snippet. Is it something like that is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding pseudo class can help

```css
#myList {
  background: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 6%;
  border-collapse:separate;
  border-spacing:0px 10px;
}
#myList thead {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 50%;
}
#myList tbody {
  margin-top: 20%;
}
#myList tbody td:first-child {
  display: none;
}
#myList tbody tr {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
#myList tbody td:nth-child(2) {
  border-left:1px solid;
  width: 50%;
}
#myList tbody td {
  color: #00496B;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-top:1px solid;
  border-bottom:1px solid;
}



#myList tbody:before {
  content: "-";
  display: block;
  line-height: 1em;
  color: transparent;
}
#myList tbody td:last-child {
   border-right:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table id="myList">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Product Name</td>
      <td>Qty</td>
      <td>Price</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>P1</td>
      <td>Adidas Superstar</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>$50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>P1</td>
      <td>Superstar</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>$60</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you able to solve the error of adding `box-shadow` as well? Cause i tried but i just can't get it to appear

Comment: You need to apply border box-shadow for td.. I dont think it can be applied to tr

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
tbody:before {
    content: "-";
    display: inline-block;
    color: transparent;
}
```

```css
#myList {
  background: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 6%;
}
#myList thead {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 50%;
}
tbody:before {
    content: "-";
    display: inline-block;
    color: transparent;
}
#myList tbody {
  margin-top: 20%;
}
#myList tbody td:first-child {
  display: none;
}
#myList tbody tr {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
#myList tbody td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50%;
}
#myList tbody td {
  color: #00496B;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<table id="myList">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Product Name</td>
      <td>Qty</td>
      <td>Price</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>P1</td>
      <td>Adidas Superstar</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>$50</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```